# Naive translation C++ into Julia, is there a room for optimization?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, struct, julia

Whenever I compare the performance of Julia against the monstrous C++, I always get impressed. In my own experience, many times I find Julia on par with or even faster than C++. My last experiment was comparing Julia speed against [C++ Armadillo library](http://arma.sourceforge.net/speed.html) using their micro benchmarks. In most cases, I found Julia way faster than C++ in such numerical code (caution: these are my own claims, YMMV of course).

Now, I did a naive translation of [this ray-triangle intersection C++ code](https://github.com/johnnovak/raytriangle-test/blob/master/cpp/perftest.cpp) into Julia and expected to get similar results as my previous experiments. Running both codes, I got the following result for C++ (compiled with: gcc -std=c++11 -lm -O3 -ffast-math):

```
Total intersection tests:  100,000,000
  Hits:                      4,930,610 ( 4.93%)
  Misses:                   95,069,390 (95.07%)

Total time:                       1.51 seconds
Millions of tests per second:    66.18
```

and for Julia (Version 0.6.0 on Windows 10), I got:

```
Total intersection tests:  100000000
  Hits:             5221395  ( 5.221395%)
  Misses:           94778605 (94.778605%)

Total time:         2.144723297 seconds
Millions of tests per second:   46.6260613384851
```

The following is a line-by-line translation into Julia without any attempt to optimize. What is wrong with my code? or is Julia `struct` less efficient? Where does this `1.4X` come from? and how can I optimize this code? I'm aware that I use double-precision, but this is not a problem in Julia.

```
struct vec3
  x::Float64
  y::Float64
  z::Float64
end

mutable struct ray  
  orig::vec3
  dir ::vec3
end

sub3(a::vec3, b::vec3) = vec3(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y, a.z - b.z)
dot3(a::vec3, b::vec3) = a.x*b.x +  a.y*b.y + a.z*b.z
len(v::vec3) = sqrt( v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y + v.z * v.z  )
normalize(v) = begin l = length(v); vec3( v[1]/l, v[2]/l, v[3]/l ) end
cross3(a::vec3, b::vec3) = vec3(a.y*b.z - a.z*b.y, a.z*b.x - a.x*b.z, a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x)

# Ray-triangle intersection routine 
function rayTriangleIntersect(r::ray, v0::vec3, v1::vec3, v2::vec3)::Float64
  v0v1 = sub3(v1, v0);
  v0v2 = sub3(v2, v0);
  pvec = cross3(r.dir, v0v2);
  detc = dot3(v0v1, pvec);

  (detc < 0.000001) && return -Inf

  invDet = 1.0 / detc;
  tvec = sub3(r.orig, v0);
  u = dot3(tvec, pvec) * invDet;

  (u < 0 || u > 1) && return -Inf

  qvec = cross3(tvec, v0v1);
  v = dot3(r.dir, qvec) * invDet;

  (v < 0 || u + v > 1) && return -Inf 

  return dot3( v0v2, qvec ) * invDet;
end

function randomSphere()::vec3
  r1  = rand();
  r2  = rand();
  lat = acos(2r1 - 1) - pi/2;
  lon = 2pi * r2;
  return vec3( cos(lat)cos(lon), cos(lat)sin(lon), sin(lat) )
end    

function generateRandomTriangles(numTriangles::Int64)#::Array{vec3}(3numTriangles)
  vertices = Array{vec3}(3numTriangles)    
  for i = 1:3numTriangles
    vertices[i] = randomSphere();
  end
  return vertices
end

function main_ray()
  const NUM_RAYS = 1000;
  const NUM_TRIANGLES = 100 * 1000;

  vertices = generateRandomTriangles(NUM_TRIANGLES);
  const numVertices = NUM_TRIANGLES * 3;

  numHit  = 0;
  numMiss = 0;

  o  = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
  d  = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
  p1 = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
  r  = ray(o,d)

  tTotal = @elapsed for i = 1:NUM_RAYS
    r.orig = randomSphere();
    p1     = randomSphere();
    r.dir  = sub3(p1,r.orig); 

    for j = 0:div(numVertices,3) - 1
      t = rayTriangleIntersect(r, vertices[j*3 + 1],
                                  vertices[j*3 + 2],
                                  vertices[j*3 + 3]);
      t >= 0? numHit+=1 : numMiss+=1
    end
  end

  numTests = NUM_RAYS * NUM_TRIANGLES;
  hitPerc  = numHit / numTests * 100.0
  missPerc = numMiss / numTests * 100.0
  mTestsPerSecond = numTests / tTotal / 10^6

  println("Total intersection tests:  $numTests");
  println("  Hits:\t\t\t    $numHit  ( $hitPerc%)");
  println("  Misses:\t\t    $numMiss ($missPerc%)\n");
  println("Total time:\t\t\t$tTotal seconds");
  println("Millions of tests per second:\t$mTestsPerSecond\n");    
end

main_ray();
```

Comment: Why are the structs `vec3` and `ray` mutable? And is the benchmark on recent Julia (v0.6 at least)? How is the timing made (no @btime in Julia code)? All in all, the results show C++ and Julia are about the same - not even 2x for either implementation - which is expected for highly performant compiled languages. Note, the benchmark uses random number generation which is always a sink of computation time and a source for discrepancies.

Comment: @DanGetz - Thanks, I updated my results after removing `mutable` from `vec3`, and yes it improved the timings. I can't remove `mutable` from `ray`, however, I need to assign different values to `r.orig`, `p1`, and `r.dir` within the loop. The timing is calculated inside the main function over only the major loop. Julia's `rand()` is faster than C++'s anyway. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Julia is dynamically typed. I suppose even with JIT and  type annotations, this still has some performance impact.

Comment: @Don How about constructing `r` as follows: `p0 = randomSphere(); p1 = randomSphere(); r = ray(p0, sub3(p1, p0))` and this way, `ray` can be a regular `struct` (immutable) ?

Comment: "Julia is dynamically typed. I suppose even with JIT and type annotations, this still has some performance impact." No, in a type-stable function like this it will be statically typed.

Comment: Just a note: "rayTriangleIntersect(r::ray, v0::vec3, v1::vec3, v2::vec3)::Float64" You have so many type restrictions. You do know that these have nothing to do with performance, right?

Comment: Try profiling with ProfileView.jl. I think you will find, as @DanGetz says, that there may be a library function which is different between what you're using in C++ and Julia. For example, you can swap out the rng for something from RandomNumbers.jl and see how much of a difference that makes (it might make a big difference here). Additionally, did you compile the C++ with clang? The difference between gcc and clang sometimes shows up as the main source of difference in these benchmarks between C++ and Julia, sometimes doing better and sometimes doing worse.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas - Right, these type restrictions are only for debugging (or documentation). Actually, only `4*1000 rand()` are generated inside the loop, so `rand()` has no impact on performance here. Plus, Julia's `rand()` is 7X faster than C++'s. The real heavy work (the info from profiling) is inside the function  `rayTriangleIntersect`, namely, `cross3`, `dot3`, and the first conditional. I compiled C++ using GCC: `gcc -std=c++11 -lm -O3 -ffast-math`.

Comment: If this code is to be written in a more "Julian" way, maybe `Vectors`, `Arrays` or other structs, to give the maximum possible speed out of the language, what do you suggest? I tried to use, e.g., `SVector`s instead of `vec3` and all functions are passing `SVector`s; `randomSphere()` returns an SVector,  `vertices` is an `Array{SVector{3,Float64}}(n)`, internal `cross` and `dot` are used, etc. Finally, I got the same or slightly worse results (`43.87 Million test/s`). I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try to make `ray` an immutable struct (like I suggested in the last comment)? This is the Julian way (at least for now)

Comment: @DanGetz - Yes, your suggestion was very nice and clean, sorry for not giving you feedback at time, but the performance improvement was unnoticeable. The original implementation was a true C++-like style, so I was wondering if another style (scientific computing style heavily uses Arrays, Vectors, etc, conf. Fortran style, Matlab, etc) was appropriate or more performant. I already tried `SVector`s instead of `vec3` without much success. Operations in the hot inner loop function are the culprit, `cross3`, `dot3`, the conditional, etc. I can post the `SVector`s attempt if you like to check.

Comment: OK. More ideas: use `inv(x)` instead of `1.0/x`. And use `srand` to benchmark identical runs.

Answer (score 0):

That's the kind of code that really profits from starting julia with -O3 and while at it you might also add a --math-mode=fast.
With that, the timings on my machine go from 8.6s to 3.2s.
I'm also using Float32 as in the C++ code, since that can make a difference here.
Adding an @inline to triangle intersects adds a speed up as well (1.9s now), guess it can better optimize the for loop body than!

Here is the slightly differently structured code:

```
    using StaticArrays
    const vec3 = SVector{3, Float32}
    struct ray
      orig::vec3
      dir ::vec3
    end

    # Ray-triangle intersection routine
    @inline function rayTriangleIntersect(r::ray, v0::vec3, v1::vec3, v2::vec3)::Float64
      v0v1 = v1 .- v0
      v0v2 = v2 .- v0
      pvec = cross(r.dir, v0v2);
      detc = dot(v0v1, pvec);

      (detc  1) && return -Inf32

      qvec = cross(tvec, v0v1);
      v = dot(r.dir, qvec) * invDet;

      (v  1) && return -Inf32

      return dot( v0v2, qvec ) * invDet;
    end

    function randomSphere()::vec3
      r1  = rand(Float32);
      r2  = rand(Float32);
      lat = acos(2r1 - 1) - pi/2f0;
      lon = 2f0*pi * r2;
      return vec3(cos(lat)cos(lon), cos(lat)sin(lon), sin(lat) )
    end

    function generateRandomTriangles(numTriangles::Int64)#::Array{vec3}(3numTriangles)
      vertices = Array{vec3}(3numTriangles)
      for i = 1:3numTriangles
        vertices[i] = randomSphere();
      end
      return vertices
    end

    function main_ray(vertices)
        o  = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        d  = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        p1 = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        r  = ray(o,d)
      numHit  = 0;
      numVertices = length(vertices)
      for i = 1:1000
        p1 = randomSphere();
        r = ray(
            randomSphere(),
            (p1 .- r.orig)
        )

        @simd for j = 0:div(numVertices,3) - 1
         @inbounds  t = rayTriangleIntersect(r, vertices[j*3 + 1],
                                      vertices[j*3 + 2],
                                      vertices[j*3 + 3]);
          numHit += ifelse(t >= 0, 1, 0)
        end
      end
    end

    NUM_TRIANGLES = 100 * 1000;

    vertices = generateRandomTriangles(NUM_TRIANGLES);

    using BenchmarkTools
    b = @benchmark main_ray(vertices)
    println(b)
```